# Add inbound rule to security group aws cdk

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-cdk, aws-security-group

I am working with `AWS Opensearch (Elasticsearch 6.8)` and an AWS lambda. The lambda inserts records into Elasticsearch when an event is received. Below is how the elasticsearch is defined:

```
this.loggingES = new opensearch.Domain(this, 'LogsES', {
    version: opensearch.EngineVersion.ELASTICSEARCH_6_8,
    domainName: "app-logs-es",
    vpc: this.loggingVPC,
    zoneAwareness: {
        availabilityZoneCount: 3,
    },
    enforceHttps: true,
    nodeToNodeEncryption: true,
    encryptionAtRest: {
        enabled: true
    },
    capacity: {
        masterNodes: 3,
        dataNodes: 3,
    }
});
```

Now what happens is, two security groups get created under the same VPC, one for the ES and another for the lambda. The lambda is unable to connect to the Elasticsearch because the elasticsearch security group doesn't have an inbound rule setup that allows traffic from lambda security group.

#### Is there a way, I can either:

- Define a VPC that only has a single security group and all components inside the VPC can access each other?
- Or in the CDK itself, I can setup an inbound rule in Elasticsearch SG to allow traffic from lambda SG.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup, CDK makes this very easy with the [`Connections`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.Connections.html#allowwbrdefaultwbrportwbrfromother-description) class, which `Domain` [exposes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_opensearchservice.Domain.html#connections). Here's an example in Python:

```python
my_domain.connections.allow_default_port_from(my_lambda)
```

And that's it. You don't have to think about security groups, they're abstracted away.

Comment: This solution works like a charm. Although I was working with `TypeScript` but was able to port the code. Thanks for the intuition. I've added a TypeScript variant as an answer too for others.

Answer (score 1):

In CDK it's possible to add ingress rule, as follows:

```
const mySecurityGroup = new ec2.SecurityGroup(this, 'SecurityGroup', {
   vpc,
   description: 'Allow ssh access to ec2 instances',
   allowAllOutbound: true   // Can be set to false
});

mySecurityGroup.addIngressRule(ec2.Peer.anyIpv4(), ec2.Port.tcp(22), 
'allow ssh access from the world');
```

The example is taken from the official documentation page:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ec2.SecurityGroup.html#example.

Comment: This is discouraged - check my answer for an idiomatic way. From the docs: `Direct manipulation of the Security Group through addIngressRule and addEgressRule is possible, but mutation through the .connections object is recommended. If you peer two constructs with security groups this way, appropriate rules will be created in both.`

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @gshpychka is spot on and very concise. Adding the code below for anyone looking for a `TypeScript` variant.

```
import {Port} from "@aws-cdk/aws-ec2"

// ... other imports and code

MyOpenSearchDomain.connections.allowFrom(myLambda, Port.allTraffic(), "Allows Lambda to connect to Opensearch.")
```

> To allow connections from Lambda we need to specify `Port.allTraffic()` since a Lambda does not have a default port. Using `allow_default_port_from` would throw an error stating the same.

Comment: Regarding your comment about the default port, it refers to the default port of the domain, not the lambda. From the docs: `Allow connections from the peer on our default port.`.